# Signin Fails With Custom Errors

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djongo

Signin is working flawlessly but, Signup returns with {"non_field_errors": ["Incorrect creds"]}

Which I have specified in LoginSerializer. I think it's happening due to authenticate function but, I am not able to pinpoint the issue as when I print it, it returns None. Does anybody knows what could be the issue? I have given the whole code but, I reckon the problem is created in LoginSerializer.I have also, added the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in settings.py and after then, it's still gives that error.

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser

class UserManager (BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Username should be provided")
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password (password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)

class User (AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField (primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models. CharField (max_length=60)
    password = models. CharField (max_length=16)
    username = models. CharField (max_length=100, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    objects = UserManager()
```

Serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    email = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'name')
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=validated_data['username'],
                password=validated_data['password'],
                email=validated_data['email'],
                name=validated_data['name']
            )
            return user

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = authenticate(attrs)   //this is returning None
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect creds")
```

Views:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer, LoginSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework import status
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

class SignUpView (APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            return JsonResponse({
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token),
            }, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse (serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class SignInView (APIView):
    def post (self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            return JsonResponse({
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token),
            }, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return JsonResponse ({'user': user}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return JsonResponse (serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

settings:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'hide_it'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'eCommerceApp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'eCommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'eCommerceApp.User'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ]
}

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eCommerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'ecommerce',
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Try to create user and authenticate user in terminal using django shell. If it works well then your concern of that there is something wrong with authenticate will be removed.